# What is the correct way to install an auto-updated app in Windows?

Tags: windows, installation

I'm adding auto-update capabilities to an existing app (java launched via exe4j).  Everything works fine for an administrator, but non-admins won't have write access to the installed directory (`c:\program files\myApp`).

All the solutions I've come up with feel a bit evil, so I thought I'd ask here.  Here are the ideas I've had so far:

- Granting everyone write access to a sub-directory in my program's install dir (eg `c:\program files\myApp\bin`).
- Only installing a small boostrap to program files, and installing the rest to the user's home (maybe under AppData).  This would mean every user would have a duplicate copy of most of the application.
- Installing the entire app in the user's home dir

What's the most correct/least evil way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way would be installing your app in **%userprofile%\AppData\Local**

If your app isn't very large, that's your best option. For example this is the way Google Chrome works.

Answer (score 0):

All your ideas have a security issue: anyone could change the program files easily. Google Chrome has the same security issue: it is much more easier for malware to modify its files.

I would definitely not recommend changing the default permissions in `C:\Program Files\myApp\bin`.

If you want to prevent duplication, you can use `C:\ProgramData`, it is less strict with permission as `Program Files` but has the same security risks.

So if you care about user's security, you should install the application into `Program Files`. Thus you get the system protection for your files from being unintentionally modified.

Your updater application elevates before writing new files to `Program Files`. The downside is that users have to click *Continue* button in the UAC prompt. If updates are rather rare, it is the easiest way to go. Mozilla Firefox used to use this approach: the browser downloaded the update, on the next launch it shows UAC confirmation and writes the updated files to `Program Files`.

Recently Firefox changed its update experience. They install a service that handles the update. That way users are not bothered with UAC confirmation, everything happens transparently to them. They start Firefox, if there's an update, the service is started, since the service runs with system privileges it has write access to Program Files, the files are updated, then the update Firefox is started, and the service shuts down (until the next update).

I like Firefox approach much more: its files are protected from unintentional modification by file system permissions. At the same time, now it updates silently; before they implemented update service, I didn't mind to press *Continue* in the UAC prompt once in three months.